# Subform to search record on main form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, record, subform

I have a subform like so:

[image]

When i click the 'select' button, i wish for the record on the main form to navigate to the appropriate one (the one which holds the same Staff ID).

What I have tried so far is for when the button is pressed to run the following vba:

```vb
Private Sub Command6_Click()
Dim rs As Object
Dim strLinkValue As String
strLinkValue = Forms![navigation form]![NavigationSubform]![teacher search qry subform]![Staff ID].Value
Set rs = Forms![navigation form]![NavigationSubform]![teacher search qry subform].Form.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[Staff ID] = '" & strLinkValue & "'"
Forms![navigation form]![NavigationSubform].Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

But when I do this I get run-time error 438 (object doesn't support this property or method).

Any ideas? I feel like I'm over-complicating things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first got error 438 (*"Object doesn't support this property or method."*) at this line ...

```vb
Set rs = Forms![navigation form]![NavigationSubform].Recordset.Clone
```

Changing from `Recordset.Clone` to `Form.RecordsetClone` cured the error (at that line).

Unfortunately you then got error 438 again when attempting to set `Bookmark` at this line ...

```vb
Forms![navigation form]![NavigationSubform].Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

The reason for the error at that point was because `[NavigationSubform]` is a subform control, and a control does not have a `Bookmark` property.  You need to set the `Bookmark` on the `Form` contained within that control.

This code does what I believe you want.  I tested it in Access 2010 with a copy of your database.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strLinkValue As String

strLinkValue = Me![Staff ID].Value
With Me.Parent.Form
    Set rs = .RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[Staff ID] = '" & strLinkValue & "'"
    .Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End With
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations sections of all your modules and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about and then try compile again.  Repeat until all compile errors have been eliminated.